# Multiple Driver Nets on output of IOBUF

Tags: vhdl, spi, vivado

I wrote the following module which shall act as a switch between a standard 4-wire SPI and the 3-wire SPI of an AD9637 ADC.
Therefore I instantiated an IOBUF, count clock edges and switch the IOBUF from output to input after the 16th clock cycle, where the ADC starts to put out data on the shared line.
However, I get e `Multiple Driver Nets` error, trying to implement the design in Vivado 2019.1 and I cannot wrap my head around why this happens, as in my description, the affected signal `io_SDIO` is only driven by the `IO` pin of the instantiated IOBUF.
The full error is

```
[DRC MDRV-1] Multiple Driver Nets: Net zsys_i/SPI_3wire_adapter_AD_0/U0/o_MISO has multiple drivers: zsys_i/SPI_3wire_adapter_AD_0/U0/IOBUF_inst/IBUF/O, and zsys_i/SPI_3wire_adapter_AD_0/U0/o_MISO_reg/Q.
```

The full design is

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

Library UNISIM;
use UNISIM.vcomponents.all;

entity SPI_3wire_adapter_AD9637 is
    port (
        o_count : out std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
        o_enable : out std_logic;
    
        i_SCLK :    in STD_LOGIC;           --PS side clock on which the module operates syncronously
        i_MOSI :    in STD_LOGIC;           --MOSI PS side (input)
        o_MISO :    out STD_LOGIC;          --MISO PS side (output)
        i_CS :      in STD_LOGIC;           --CS PS side (input)
    
        o_SCLK :    out STD_LOGIC;          --SPI clock (output)
        o_CS :      out STD_LOGIC;          --SPI CS (output)
        io_SDIO :   inout STD_LOGIC         --SPI SDIO - shared MOSI/MISO for 3-wire SPI (output/input)
    );
end SPI_3wire_adapter_AD9637;

architecture behavioral of SPI_3wire_adapter_AD9637 is

    signal s_CLK_count: integer range 0 to 23 := 0;
    signal s_N_enable_output : STD_LOGIC := '0';

begin

IOBUF_inst : IOBUF
generic map (
   DRIVE => 12,
   IOSTANDARD => "DEFAULT",
   SLEW => "SLOW")
port map (
   O => o_MISO,             -- Buffer output
   IO => io_SDIO,           -- Buffer inout port (connect directly to top-level port)
   I => i_MOSI,             -- Buffer input
   T => s_N_enable_output   -- 3-state enable input, high=input, low=output
);

o_CS <= i_CS;
o_SCLK <= i_SCLK;

o_count <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(s_CLK_count, 5));
o_enable <= s_N_enable_output;

    process(i_SCLK, i_CS)
    begin
        if falling_edge(i_CS) then
            -- Reset CLK_count and turn IOBUF into output mode
            s_CLK_count <= 0;
            s_N_enable_output <= '0'; -- set IOBUF to output mode
        end if;
        
        if falling_edge(i_SCLK) then
            if s_CLK_count = 16 then
                -- on the 16th clk edge switch to input mode
                s_N_enable_output <= '1'; -- set IOBUF to input mode
            end if;
            
            -- on all falling clk edges increment the CLK_count if active
            if i_CS = '0' then
                s_CLK_count <= s_CLK_count + 1;
            end if;
            
            if i_CS = '1' then
                -- use the falling clk edges to reset the system if inactive, i.e., CS == 1
                s_N_enable_output <= '1'; -- set IOBUF to input modde
            end if;
        end if;
        
    end process;

end behavioral;
```

My approach to the design was to create a signal `s_N_enable_output` which represents the desired input/output mode of the IOBUF and drive the T pin of the IOBUF with this signal only. By onyl mapping the shared data line to the inout port and not driving it directly in the process I was hoping to avoid such Multiple Driver Nets errors.

EDIT: I have overlooked that there is another Multiple Driver Nets error on the o_MISO pin:

```
[DRC MDRV-1] Multiple Driver Nets: Net zsys_i/SPI_3wire_adapter_AD_0/U0/o_MISO has multiple drivers: zsys_i/SPI_3wire_adapter_AD_0/U0/IOBUF_inst/IBUF/O, and zsys_i/SPI_3wire_adapter_AD_0/U0/o_MISO_reg/Q.
```

Comment: Your design contains VHDL constructs which are not suited for synthesis:
1.
The process is sensitive to 2 signals, which are used as clock-signals.
But for synthesis only processes sensitive to 1 clock signal are allowed.
2.
You change the signal s_N_enable_output with a falling edge of i_CS and also with a falling edge of i_SCLK (same with signal s_CLK_count).
So in synthesis a flipflop would be needed with 2 clock inputs, which does not exist (or the 2 clock signals must be combined to a single one, which will also cause severe problems).

Comment: So I think there must be other error messages also.
And the error message you showed here does not fit into the code you provided, as there is no instance o_MISO_reg.

Comment: Thanks @MatthiasSchweikart ! I understand, that such a FF doesn't exist - thanks for point that out.
Regarding your second comment, this definitely is the code that produced exactly those two errors. The instance o_MISO_reg is a synthesis product, I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the design suitable for synthesis and implementation by introducing an intermidiate signal `s_CLK_count_greater_15` and handling all the "state changes" in one process:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

Library UNISIM;
use UNISIM.vcomponents.all;

entity SPI_3wire_adapter_AD9637 is
    port (
        o_count : out std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
        o_enable : out std_logic;
    
        i_SCLK :    in STD_LOGIC;           --PS side clock on which the module operates syncronously
        i_MOSI :    in STD_LOGIC;           --MOSI PS side (input)
        o_MISO :    out STD_LOGIC;          --MISO PS side (output)
        i_CS :      in STD_LOGIC;           --CS PS side (input)
    
        o_SCLK :    out STD_LOGIC;          --SPI clock (output)
        o_CS :      out STD_LOGIC;          --SPI CS (output)
        io_SDIO :   inout STD_LOGIC         --SPI SDIO - shared MOSI/MISO for 3-wire SPI (output/input)
    );
end SPI_3wire_adapter_AD9637;

architecture behavioral of SPI_3wire_adapter_AD9637 is

    signal s_CLK_count: integer range 0 to 23 := 0;
    signal s_IN_notOUT : STD_LOGIC;
    signal s_CLK_count_greater_15 : STD_LOGIC;

begin

IOBUF_inst : IOBUF
generic map (
   DRIVE => 12,
   IOSTANDARD => "DEFAULT",
   SLEW => "SLOW")
port map (
   O => o_MISO,             -- Buffer output
   IO => io_SDIO,           -- Buffer inout port (connect directly to top-level port)
   I => i_MOSI,             -- Buffer input
   T => s_IN_notOUT         -- 3-state enable input, high=input, low=output
);

o_CS <= i_CS;
o_SCLK <= i_SCLK;

o_count <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(s_CLK_count, 5));
s_IN_notOUT <= not i_CS and s_CLK_count_greater_15;
o_enable <= s_IN_notOUT;

process(i_SCLK)
begin
    if falling_edge(i_SCLK) then
        
        if i_CS = '1' then
            s_CLK_count <= 0;          
        else
            s_CLK_count <= s_CLK_count + 1; -- on all falling clk edges increment the CLK_count if CS is low
        end if;
        
        if s_CLK_count > 15 then
            s_CLK_count_greater_15 <= '1';
        else
            s_CLK_count_greater_15 <= '0';
        end if;
        
    end if;
end process;

end behavioral;
```